# tableView doesn't display my data

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I'm trying to fetch data from an API but the data does not get displayed.

```
Alamofire.request(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseJSON {
        response in

        //getting json
        if let json = response.result.value {
            print("typppppe:\(type(of: json))")
            //converting json to NSArray                                          

            let commentArray = json as! NSArray
            let dictName = commentArray["name"].value
            let dictBody = commentArray["body"].stringValue as? String ?? ""
            print("namessss\(dictName)")
            print("bodyssss\(dictBody)")
            print("commm:\(commentArray)")

            let comment = Comment.init(commentName: dictName, commentBody: dictBody)
            self.comments.append(comment)
            self.commentTableJson.reloadData()

        }
    }
```

[image: some of api data]

The problem in this function is how to fix so that the data in `tableViewCell` is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to run loop for comments json.

```
    let str = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments"
    let url = URL(string: str)
    Alamofire.request(url! ,  method: .get).responseJSON { (dataResponse) in

        print(dataResponse.result.value)
        if dataResponse.result.isSuccess {
            if let arrCommentsJson = dataResponse.result.value! as? [[String: Any]] {
                for comment in arrCommentsJson {
                    let dictName = comment["name"]
                    let dictBody = comment["body"]
                    let comment = Comment.init(commentName: dictName, commentBody: dictBody)
                    self.comments.append(comment)

                }
                    self.commentTableJson.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not call `reloadData` in the loop. Call it once after the loop.